# How to get a full website path from a relative website path using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am implementing a web crawler and I am trying to parse the links in HTML. I can follow full website paths, but some relative paths get a little weird.

I can follow full paths, ie `http://foo.com/bar/baz` and I was able to find a way to follow relative paths, ie `/qux` by using the following functions:

```
def baseUrl(url):
    u = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    return "{}://{}{}/".format(u.scheme, u.netloc, '/'.join(u.path.split('/')[:-1]))

def fullUrl(url, parent):
    u = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    if u.scheme:
        return url.split("/#")[0]
    else:
        return "{}{}".format(baseUrl(parent), url).split("/#")[0]
```

But sometimes, the website url is `http://foo.com/bar/baz`, and in the HTML, there is something like `<a href='/bar/qux'`. The target url should be `http://foo.com/bar/qux`, but my code is outputting `http://foo.com/bar//bar/qux`.

Does anyone know of a general way to figure out which parts match up between the two URLs in order to find out what the full path would be from a relative path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I always do and it worked for me so far is to call [`urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) with the current page URL:

```
>>> from urlparse import urljoin
>>> urljoin("http://foo.com/bar/baz", "/bar/qux")
'http://foo.com/bar/qux'
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: I have another (related) issue. Sometimes, when I'm crawling, the URL I go to would be something like `http://foo.com/bar` and it redirects to `http://foo.com/bar/`. Because of the redirect, it would look for an incorrect relative path. Do you know how I could fix that?

Thank you again!

Comment: @Brian quick and dirty fix would be to use `url.rstrip("/")`, though make sure it would not break other use cases. Thanks.

Comment: @alexce, my issue is actually the opposite. The url I crawled to was `http://foo.com/bar`, and (in a browser) it redirects to `http://foo.com/bar/` (since it is a directory). Thus, when I tried to crawl to `/baz`, it went to `http://foo.com/baz` instead of `http://foo.com/bar/baz`.

Comment: @Brian hm, but if you have `/baz` relative URL, it is actually correct that the join gives you the `http://foo.com/baz`, isn't it? Both `urljoin("http://foo.com/bar/", "/baz")` and `urljoin("http://foo.com/bar", "/baz")` would produce `http://foo.com/baz`. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: @alexce, I realize my comment wasn't true to my issue. The problem lies with relative URLs like `../qux`. `urlparse.urljoin('http://foo.com/bar/baz/','../qux')`->`'http://foo.com/bar/qux'`, but `urlparse.urljoin('http://foo.com/bar/baz','../qux')`->`'http://foo.com/qux'`.

Comment: @Brian ah, gotcha, `urljoin()` actually follows the spec here. I am afraid you would have to handle this use case manually..may be checking the base url if it ends with `/` or not and append if needed. Thanks.